# Does Batman know he's Superman's boss since he owns the Daily Planet?

Tags: dc, batman, superman

Well, after it was mentioned in a quiz TV show, I suddenly discovered that Bruce Wayne owns the Daily Planet, and so I wanted to ask. In any comic has it been shown that Batman knows that Superman's alter-ego works for him, or that Superman knows that Batman's alter-ego Bruce Wayne is his boss? Or do they not know that little detail?

Comment: Oh, Batman owns the _Planet_? Where's that from? (Issue number, cartoon, anything) - EDIT: Ah nevermind, found [that](https://www.huffpost.com/entry/batman-is-secretly-supermans-boss_n_56e82ba7e4b065e2e3d74c45), although I'd be curious to know if you have other occurrences of that thing :)

Comment: I'm now imagining an alternate cut of *Batman vs Superman* where that's what they bond over instead of the "Martha" thing.

Comment: @F1Krazy *Batman:* "When the *Daily Planet* arrives at my doorstep, I'll see your death on the front page!" *Superman:* "You subscribe to the *Daily Planet*? So do I! They've got the best reporters, like Clark Kent!" *Batman:* "Yeah, that Bruce Wayne fellow who owns it is definitely committed to quality journalism!"

Comment: "Mr Wayne, I want a raise." "I'll think about it." "I wasn't asking." "Fair enough."

Comment: Same was mentioned in BVS. I guess at the Lex's party.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is yes. Apparently this all happened in [Batman:Hush](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_Hush) as [noted here](https://warnerbros.fandom.com/wiki/Daily_Planet)

> In the Batman: Hush storyline, it is named a subsidiary of Wayne Entertainment.

[image]

Batman has [known Superman's secret identity for a long time](https://www.reddit.com/r/DCcomics/comments/463vwd/when_did_superman_and_batman_first_learn_each/) (since [Superman Vol1, #76 in 1952](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Superman_Vol_1_76)) so it's unlikely he wouldn't have known he was Kent's boss. It's even weirder because [he bought it from Lex Luthor](https://www.huffpost.com/entry/batman-is-secretly-supermans-boss_n_56e82ba7e4b065e2e3d74c45)

> Both Wayne and Kent know the truth about each other’s alter egos by the period when Wayne purchased The Daily Planet, so we can guess this was certainly some sort of power move by Batman. Perhaps Wayne’s main motivation for buying the The Daily Planet was to save the paper from Luthor, but let’s be real about these fictional superheroes, there’s no way ego wasn’t a part of his calculation.
>
> How much influence Wayne has had over the publication’s reporting remains unclear. Presumably, Wayne had a few tips on dimly lit, tall building ledges for the crime beat reporter. But unfortunately, “Help!” writer Jeph Loeb was unavailable to clarify the motives of the characters, as he now works as the executive vice president of Marvel Television.

Comment: Is that newspaper guy supposed to look like JJ Jameson?